# Custom Validator function with Button on Client Click - Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, validation, customvalidator

I have a textbox to which I have assigned a CustomValidator which has a ClientValidationFunction="txtcheck"

ASPX:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txt1"  MaxLength="10" CssClass="class1" Width="90%" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:CustomValidator runat="server" ID="valtxt1" ControlToValidate="txt1" ValidateEmptyText="true" ValidationGroup="Save" Display="Dynamic"
                        ClientValidationFunction="txtcheck" Font-Italic="True"></asp:CustomValidator>
```

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSave" Text="Save" CausesValidation="True" runat="server" ValidationGroup="Save" OnClientClick="show()" UseSubmitBehavior="false" />
```

Javascript :

The alert messge is mandatory as it is required.

```
function txtcheck(source, args) {
Alert('incorrect value');
args.IsValid = false;
}

function show(){
var validated = Page_ClientValidate('valSave');
    if (validated) {
-- show some data.
      }
}
```

*On click of Save Button I do a Page_ClientValidate to check other controls.*

The issue is, on click of Save; txtcheck() is getting called twice.
Once via the CustomValidator & other when I do the Page_ClientValidate. Due to this the Alert message is also shown twice.

Pls guide as to how to call the txtcheck() only once & show alert once.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you invoking ```txtcheck()``` inside of ```Page_ClientValidate()``` besides having it in your customValidator?

Comment: @invinciblemuffi : No, I am not explicitly invoking the txtcheck();

Comment: Can you put breakpoint at ```Page_ClientValidate``` and check how many times the function is fired?